# Make SublimeLinter show error codes

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimelinter

If I run `flake8` at the terminal, it gives me alphanumeric error codes for every error - like F401 for an unused import:

```
$ flake8 ~/test.py
/Users/markamery/test.py:1:1: F401 'math' imported but unused
```

However, when I use [SublimeLinter-flake8](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-flake8) to lint code in Sublime, these codes aren't included in the error message shown in the status bar:

[image: Screenshot showing the message above in the Sublime status bar, but without an error code]

How can I make the error codes appear in the status tray, like they do at the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SublimeLinter's settings file now contains a message template parameter which defaults to showing only the error message, documented as follows in the default settings file:

```js
// Show the messages for problems at your cursor position.
// - {message} will be replaced by the actual messages.
// - {linter} will be replaced by the linter reporting the error.
// - {type} will be replaced by either warning or error.
// - {code} will be replaced by the error code.
// Set to "" to display nothing
"statusbar.messages_template": "{message}",
```

To show error codes, then, you need to:

1. Open the SublimeLinter settings file. (On Sublime Text 3 on a Mac, I can access this via *Sublime Text* -> *Preferences* -> *Package Settings* -> *Sublime Linter* -> *Settings*; the menus will be slightly different in different environments.)

   [image: Screenshot showing the menus above]
2. In the "User" settings in the right-hand-pane of the split window that opens, add a `"statusbar.messages_template"` parameter that contains a `{code}` placeholder. For example, I use `"{type} {code}: {message}"` as my template:

   [image: Screenshot showing the following code in the SublimeLinter.sublime-settings - User file: <code>{"statusbar.messages_template": "{type} {code}: {message}"}</code>. Sorry, I can't format this sensibly within alt-text!]
3. Save, and the messages shown in the status bar by SublimeLinter will henceforth contain the error code:

   [image: Status bar screenshot showing "flake8(1|0), warning F401: 'math' imported but unused, Line 1, Column 12]